# Iesi.Collections official page

Tags: .net, nhibernate, iesi-collections

Iesi.Collections.dll is shipped with nHibernate and has some good collections worth reusing. However I cannot find any official documentation page for them, and it might be dangerous to use unversioned undocumented library in the production, especially when a new nHibernate gets released breaking undocumented API.

Where do I find the official page?